# n! BigInteger makes a loop

Tags: java, loops, biginteger

I've written this little program to find n!:

```
public class Fattoriale {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            int n;
            do {
                n = Input.readInt("Enter an int number ( int >=0)");
            while( n < 0);
            long fatt = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
                fatta = fatt * i;
            }
            System.out.println(n"+!" + " = " + fatt);
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite this program using BigInteger. I've written this:

```
    import jbook.util.*;

import java.math.*;
public class Fattoriale {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String s = Input.readString("Enter an int number. ");
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(s);
        BigInteger tot = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2");

        for (; i.compareTo(big) < 0; i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
            tot = tot.multiply(i);

        }

        System.out.println(tot);

    }
}
```

But this program with BigInteger makes a loop and I can't understand why. I hope somebody can help me. Thank you very much ;). (nb. ignore Input class, it's only a class that I created to enter input faster)

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to use a `BigInteger` for `i`? I can see how your total (`tot`) could easily get very large, but if you're trying to take `n!` where `n>Integer.MAX_VALUE`, I suspect it's going to take a very long time...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha indicates that your answer will require more than 10 GB to store if `i` is too big for a 32-bit integer: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2000000000%21&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be like this because `i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` doesn't update the variable `i`.

```
for (; i.compareTo(big) <= 0; i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    tot = tot.multiply(i);
}
```

There are two changes:

1. It should be `<=0` instead of `<0`
2. Assign it back to `i` to update it.

How to confirm?

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2");
System.out.println(i.add(BigInteger.ONE));   // print 3
System.out.println(i);                       // print 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've forgotten the <=, too!

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` is immutable, so unless you set a new value for it using the `=` operator, its value doesn't change. Thus, each time in the loop that you call `i.add(BigInteger.ONE)`, the computer calculates i+1 and then throws away the result. Instead, try:

```
for (; i.compareTo(big) < 0; i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
```